# Insert to locale `json` File without any modules via node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Can I Insert a `name` to locale.json without any modules?

This is my json File and I want to store `john` in That.

```
const locale = require('./locale.json');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it without any modules, but you can do it with core modules like `fs`. But this is not as easy as it may seem. You need to read the file, parse the JSON, update the object, serialize to JSON again and write the file, all that handling the errors correctly and making sure that nothing will get read while the write is in progress and that no writes will happen at the same time, handling race conditions. Not that easy. A lot of locking, synchronization and error checking. See this answer for more info to a similar problem:

- [Write JSON with query pseudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40863991/write-json-with-query-pseudo/40864731#40864731)